# WebDriverWait.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'timeout'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am receiving this error on wait command.

```
element = WebDriverWait('self.driver, 10').until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'user-name-input')))
TypeError: WebDriverWait.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'timeout'
```

these are my commands, What do I miss here?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import selenium
import selenium_elements
import webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver
from webbrowser import Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
browser = Chrome()



webbrowser.open('https://...')
element = WebDriverWait('self.driver, 
10').until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'user-name-input')))
driver.find_element(By.ID, "user-name-input").clear()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "user-name-input").send_keys('UserName')
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'user-password-input').clear()
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'user-password-input').send_keys('Password')
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'login-submit-button').click()
driver.find_elemente(By.CLASS_NAME, 'logout-btn')
```

Comment: Remove `''` and `self.`when passing parameters to WebDriverWait.

Comment: as @matszwecja said `WebDriverWait(driver, 10)`. But first you have to use `driver.get('https://...')` instead of `webbrowser.open('https://...')`

Comment: instead of `driver.find_element(By.ID, "user-name-input").clear()` and `driver.find_element(By.ID, "user-name-input").send_keys('UserName')` you can do `element.clear()` and `element.send_keys('UserName')`

Answer (score 2):

The [`WebDriverWait()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#selenium.webdriver.support.wait.WebDriverWait) constructor  takes a WebDriver instance and timeout in seconds. Where as you have passed a *`string`*

You just need:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
```

Effectively, your line of code will be:

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'user-name-input')))
```